# Сохранится ли история после git Squash?

Tags: git

Как известно, `git` хранит историю, но что будет в этом варианте:

Я создаю новую ветку, пушу в нее 10 изменений и `RSA` ключ, к примеру, одним коммитом. Потом другим коммитом удаляю `RSA` ключ.

Если я сделаю обычный merge из нее в мастер, ключ останется в истории, а в случае со `squash`?

Comment: если Вы запушили во внешний мир свой ключ, то лучше не задавать подобный вопрос здесь, а идти и менять ключ.

Comment: @KoVadim, К счастью, я не пушу ключи, в поднятый, в докере gitlab. Просто с "ключем" легче всего донести суть вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оригинальные коммиты не будут присутствовать в истории мастера. Там будет создан один коммит с суммарными изменениями. Так что в истории мастера ключа не будет.

Но если ничего не делать, то коммиты останутся в репозитории, так как на них ссылается оригинальная ветка, из которой вы сливали изменения в мастер. Если вы после merge с опцией `--squash` удалите ветку, которую сливали, а также все другие ветки, которые используют эти коммиты, то такие коммиты станут недостижимыми (т.е. мусором). Значит, если вы почистите мусор с помощью `git gc` (или это произойдет автоматически), то оригинальные коммиты будут удалены.

Нужно понимать, что этим вы измените только *локальный* репозиторий. Вы можете удалить соответствующую ветку в remote репозитории, но изменения из нее уже мог запулить кто-то в свой репозиторий. Так что, если вы уже запушили эти коммиты, то нет никакой гарантии, что в других репозиториях они будут почищены.